# Test-Connection to Unix Server using PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell, unix

I have created the PowerShell script which works fine and I am able to automate the monitoring of the Windows server and throw alert whenever the server is down or not reachable. The script is scheduled on one particular server and it monitors all the servers listed in the script.

Now the basic command used to check the server is `Test-Connection`. I did try to do `Test-Connection` to the UNIX server and it did work for me.

Now my question is will it really work and throw me alert whenever the UNIX server is down and my script on the windows server is not able to reach it?
I was under the impression that the command is within the Windows Server area but it does not look like. Before I can go-ahead and add other Unix/Linux server, just want to be sure whether `Test-Connection` would work to Unix/Linux server also.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Did you read `Get-Help Test-Connection`?

Comment: Voted to close b/c "how does `Test-Connection` work?" isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have just tried it or red the [Test-Connection Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-5.1).

> Test-Connection sends ICMP echo request packets ("pings") to one or more computers.

So it doesn't matter which OS, the device you scan, uses and works as it needs when you connect to a Unix System.